# @property definitions with ARC: strong is the default value, but what's the default value of basic types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

As we know, under ARC rules, the default value is `strong`, so it's ok to use

```
@property NSString *downloadPath
```

But why are

```
@property (readonly) CGFloat progress
@property (readonly) BOOL isSSL
```

ok? As they are basic types, they should use `assign`. Can I understand the ARC rules as follows:

When the property is a basic type, the default value is `assign`, when the property is a object type, the default value is `strong`?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-ownership-inference-variables) on ownership inference:

> If an object is declared with retainable object owner type, but without an explicit ownership qualifier, its type is implicitly adjusted to have __strong qualification.

The reason for this can be found on the [same page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id22):

> Using strong by default is safe and consistent with the generic ARC rule about inferring ownership. It is, unfortunately, inconsistent with the non-ARC rule which states that such properties are implicitly assign. However, that rule is clearly untenable in ARC, since it leads to default-unsafe code.

As the documentation says, the default ownership qualifier is `assign`, however for retainable types (aka objects) the default qualifier is changed to `strong`, and this to help the developer in writing safe code.

Answer (score 1):

U are right! And Another default property is `atomic`.

Answer (score 0):

What could the default be?

A basic type - primitive and `struct` types - are stack allocated and their values are copied on assignment. For such types `strong`, `weak`, `unsafe_unretained` and `copy` are all meaningless - there is no heap object being referenced and values are always copied.

So none of those is going to be the default.

Which leaves `assign` (and the documentation concurs). So trust your intuition!

HTH